# GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext not releasing the file handle to the certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My method receives a file in base64 format, converts it to a byte array, and then to a local file in the webappp.

However I need to delete that file because its temporary afterwards, however I always get the error above.

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddGlobalDesignTenant([FromBody]GlobalDesignTenant globaldesigntenant)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                string domainUrl = globaldesigntenant.TestSiteCollectionUrl;
                string tenantName = domainUrl.Split('.')[0].Remove(0, 8);
                globaldesigntenant.TenantName = tenantName;

                var globalDesignTenantStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreGlobalDesignTenant;
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(globaldesigntenant.base64CertFile);

                if (File.Exists(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Temp/" + globaldesigntenant.TenantName + ".pfx"))
                {
                    File.Delete(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Temp/" + globaldesigntenant.TenantName + ".pfx");
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Temp/" + globaldesigntenant.TenantName + ".pfx", data);
                try
                {
                    using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(globaldesigntenant.TestSiteCollectionUrl,
                        globaldesigntenant.Applicationid,
                        globaldesigntenant.TenantName+".onmicrosoft.com",
                        HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Temp/" + globaldesigntenant.TenantName + ".pfx",
                        globaldesigntenant.CertificatePassword))
                    {
                        cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
                        cc.ExecuteQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Cant authenticate with those credentials");
                }              


                KeyVaultHelper keyVaultHelperPFX = new KeyVaultHelper();
                await keyVaultHelperPFX.OnCreateAsync("GlobalDesignTenantPFXFileBAse64"+ tenantName, globaldesigntenant.base64CertFile);
                globaldesigntenant.SecretIdentifierBase64PFXFile = keyVaultHelperPFX.SecretIdentifier;


                KeyVaultHelper keyVaultHelperPassword = new KeyVaultHelper();
                await keyVaultHelperPassword.OnCreateAsync("GlobalDesignTenantCertPassword" + tenantName, globaldesigntenant.CertificatePassword);
                globaldesigntenant.SecretIdentifieCertificatePassword = keyVaultHelperPassword.SecretIdentifier;

                globaldesigntenant.CertificatePassword = string.Empty;
                globaldesigntenant.base64CertFile = string.Empty;

                File.Delete(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Temp/" + globaldesigntenant.TenantName + ".pfx");

                var added = await globalDesignTenantStore.AddAsync(globaldesigntenant);
                return Ok(added);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }             
        }
```

Comment: you need to separate it into two processes, one is to get data and write data into local file then once this process is done, dispose file object. Second process is to delete that temporary file, so this can work because file object is already dispose and can be accessed

Comment: Your question should really be, `GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext` not releasing the handle to the certificate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but this seems like a bug, [source here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/AuthenticationManager.cs)

```
    public ClientContext GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(string siteUrl, string clientId, string tenant, string certificatePath, SecureString certificatePassword, AzureEnvironment environment = AzureEnvironment.Production)
    {
        var certfile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(certificatePath);
        var certificateBytes = new byte[certfile.Length];
        certfile.Read(certificateBytes, 0, (int)certfile.Length);
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(
            certificateBytes,
            certificatePassword,
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
            X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        return GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, tenant, cert, environment);
    }
```

Take note of the following line

```
var certfile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(certificatePath);
```

This returns a `FileStream` that never seems to close or dispose

**Workaround**

Read the data first (making sure you dispose), and use one of the other overloads for `GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext`